# After validation sucessfully how i redirect page in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. In my project I am trying to do field validation for this I am using bootstrap validator.

Bootstrap validator is working well but my problem is that I want after successful validation my form is submitted. Now when I click on the submit button after successful validation then it still perform nothing action.

I want after validation when I click on submit button then it will move on the function which is written in my controller.

Here is code of my view file:

```
<form class="" data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="sms_form" method="Post" action="<?php echo site_url('SMS/sendIndividualMsg/'.$row->pro_id)?>">

<div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for ="message"><strong>Message</strong></label>
                <textarea  class="form-control" id="comment_body" name="message" placeholder=" Your Message"></textarea>                
                <!-- <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("message"); ?></span> -->

                </div>
                <div>
                <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default submit send_enquiry_btn"> Send Message</button> -->
                <?php echo form_submit(['name' => 'submit' ,'class' => 'btn btn-default' , 'value' => 'Send Message']); ?>

                </div>
                </div>
```

Here is my javascript code in view file. In this code I am doing form field validation. I want when this validation is successful then form is submitted on path which is given in the form tag. Which is a name of function which is written in the controller:

```
    $('#sms_form').bootstrapValidator({            
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
          message:{
            validators: {
                regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\s]+$/,
                        message: 'The message can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    },
                     notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please supply your message'
                    }
            }
          }          
      }
  });
```

This is my function which is written in controller: I want to move on this controller after successful validation. Please help me how i solve this problem.

```
public function sendIndividualMsg($pro_id){
}
```

Please help me how i solve this problem. I am doing final year project please help me how I redirect this page:

Comment: You have not added the form in your snippet.

Comment: Something is up with your js not your php I think. Add tags to your question so it gets seen by the relevant people.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add code for redirection in your controller file.
For that please check below function.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            **"Code for validation error"**
}
else 
{
    if ($this->input->post('button_name')) {
       $result = $this->Name_of_model->name_of_function('Pass any arguments if function needed.'); 

       if($result){
           redirect('page name where you want to redirect');
       }
    }
}
```